# Verilog Include Statement Error

Tags: verilog, module

I'm trying to teach myself Verilog. I have some previous experience using VHDL. I am using Lattice Diamond as my environment.

I successfully created and simulated a full adder. I now want to use this full adder module to create an 8 bit adder.

The include statement I'm using is

```
`include "fullAdder.v"
```

and I get the following error:

```
2049990 ERROR - EightBitAdder.v(1,10-1,11) (VERI-1055) incorrect use of predefined macro include. Expected "filename"
```

further down I'm getting errors appearing in the fullAdder source

```
2049990 ERROR - fullAdder.v(3,1-33,10) (VERI-1206) overwriting previous definition of module fullAdder
```

I am trying to use the modules as shown below further down in the source file:

```
    fullAdder adder0(
    .clock      (addClock),
    .a          (a[0]),
    .b          (b[0]),
    .carryIn    (1b'0),
    .sum        (sum0),
    .carryOut   (carry0)
    );

    fullAdder adder1(
    .clock      (addClock),
    .a          (a[1]),
    .b          (b[1]),
    .carryIn    (carry0),
    .sum        (sum1),
    .carryOut   (carry1)
    );
    ...etc
```

I'm uncertain as to how I should go about fixing this. My searches haven't turned up anything helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you put it outside the module declaration?  Anyway, it's not really "best practice" to hard-code filenames like that.  Just create  filelist in a file and use `-f <filename>` switch for compile command... or put your files in a package and just call the package file for the compile command.  You will see many examples on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to `` `include `` the file at all.

Instead, simply ensure all files are in your project ready to be compiled by your EDA tool. Most (all?) EDA tools will happily compile Verilog without header files.

---

By the looks of it, you have both files being compiled by the EDA tool.

- First it elaborates `EightBitAdder.v`. You have a `` `include `` statement that copies the entire contents of `fullAdder.v` into it. This means when it compiles the file it now finds a definition of the `fullAdder` module.
- It then elaborates `fullAdder.v`, only to find another module called `fullAdder`. This results in two module definitions with the same name.

Comment: Well, that cleared up those errors. Thanks for the tip. I was expecting to have to explicitly declare all includes manually. What circumstances would require me to manually include files?

Comment: For example, defined variable for project (outside module definition).  include can also be inside def. but I rarely have a need to do so.